# On the induced module of a given Galois representation over $\mathbb{F}_p$.

Tags: functional-analysis, galois-representations

Let $K$ be a local field with perfect residue field of characteristic $p>0$ prime, and denote by $G_K$ its absolute Galois group. Let $V$ be a mod-$p$ representation of $G_K$, i.e. a finite dimension $\mathbb{F}_p$-vector space together with a linear and continuous action of $G_K$. Now we construct the following module associated to $V$ by $Ind_{G_K}(V):=Fct_{cont}(G_K, V)$, the set of all continuous maps from $G_K$ to $V$. Endow $Ind_{G_K}V$ with the discrete topology and the action of $G_K$: 
\begin{align*}
G_K \times Ind_{G_K}(V) &\to Ind_{G_K}(V) \\
g\cdot \eta &\mapsto [x\mapsto \eta(x\cdot g)]
\end{align*}
$V$ then canonically injects into $Ind_{G_K}(V)$ by sending $v\mapsto \eta_v$, where $\eta_v(g)=g(v)$ for any $g\in G_K$.
 (1) $Ind_{G_K}(V)$ should be of infinite dimensional as a $\mathbb{F}_p$-module. What is a basis of it?

(2) The Galois action on $Ind_{G_K}(V)$ seems to be transitive: solving $g\cdot \eta=h$ gives that $\eta(-)=h(-\cdot g^{-1})$, which should again lie in $Ind_{G_K}(V)$. In other words, $g$ is surjective on $Ind_{G_K}(V)$. What can you say about the image of $g-1$ on $Ind_{G_K}(V)$? Can you have a simple characterization of the image, and for which group element $g$ the image of $g-1$ is big?

(3) Suppose $g^{p^n}\to 1, n\to \infty$, can you say more on the image of $g-1$ over $Ind_{G_K}(V)$now?

Comment: I added in the text that $V$ canonically injects into $Ind_{G_K}(V)$ by sending $v\mapsto \eta_v$, where $\eta_v(g)=g(v)$ for any $g\in G_K$. I see your question, thanks,  maybe I should be careful to call it "the" induced module. But that is really the definition I want to discuss, the important thing for me is to embed $V$ into it.

Comment: I'm saying that in your definition of $Ind_{G_K}(V)$ then  $V$ is just a $F_p$-vector space, you don't start from a representation.

Comment: I just want to say, in classical terminology, $V$ is a mod-$p$ representation of $G_K$, i.e. a finite dimensional $\mathbb{F}_p$-vector space together with a linear ( since $G_K$ acts trivially on $\mathbb{F}_p$) and continuous action of $G_K$. Usually noted $V\in Rep_{\mathbb{F}_p}(G_K)$ for short.  I suppose there can be small differences on definitions of Galois representations.

Comment: Could you say more about your motivation for the question?

Comment: Hello @user45878, these questions arised when I read the first chapter of the thesis of F.T Ribeiro:  https://tel.archives-ouvertes.fr/tel-00379771/document .  He constructed a complex which is similar as Herr's complex, see:  http://www.numdam.org/article/BSMF_1998__126_4_563_0.pdf  Given a Galois representation, a functorially constructed short complex computes the Galois cohomology of it by its associated $(\phi-\gamma)$-module  (or similar modules) . Questions appear when one checks the effaceability of the functor given by computing the cohomology of the just-mentioned short complex.